# Kafka SinkRecord to Avro Object

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to build a Kafka Sink Connector, the producer is sending messages in Avro. How to convert a SinkRecord to an Avro Object

```
@Override
public void put(Collection<SinkRecord> records) {

    if(records.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("no sink records to process for current poll operation");
        return;
    }



    for (SinkRecord sinkRecord: records) {

        GenericRecord avroRecord = (GenericRecord) sinkRecord.value();

        System.out.println("(Key) Schema>>>.");
        System.out.println(sinkRecord.keySchema().doc());
        System.out.println(sinkRecord.keySchema().getClass().getName());


        System.out.println("(Value) Schema *****");
        System.out.println(sinkRecord.valueSchema().doc());
        System.out.println(sinkRecord.valueSchema().getClass().getName());

        System.out.println("(Actual) Value ===== ");
        System.out.println(sinkRecord.value());
        System.out.println(sinkRecord.value().getClass().getName());

    }
}
```

I want SinkRecord to be converted to a generated AVRO Object. Also is there a way to directly get schema from schema registry than getting schema from an .avsc file

Comment: Is there an error here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the default kafka-connect implemenation lets you specify the `value.converter.schema.registry.url` in connect.properties file to read the schema from avro records and resolve deserialize into GenericRecord.

```
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://avro-schema-registry:8081
```

And you can always extract the schemas from your sink record using `record.valueSchema()`.

Also there is an utility by confluent. You can refer it for more details :
https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-converter/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroData.java

Comment: the link is not found. Can you help to check?